# Microsoft Access to Office 365 Sharepoint on cloud

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration

I have a Microsoft Access database which has about 20 forms,  30 Queries and 5 reports.

I am planning to migrate it to a SharePoint cloud so as a newbie I have some questions:

1. Can I access SharePoint's SQL server Database (on the cloud) through SQL server management studio?
2. Where I can get the database schema of SharePoint.

Comment: SharePoint is **not** a relational database so you will have a serious challenge with those Queries. Better take a look at [Microsofts Project Sienna](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/projectsiena/)

Comment: @DannyEngelman Sienna looks like a mobile app, which i am not interesting in.